# How to fetch reference string from CKReference object

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckreference

I have two record type: `Books` & `Authors`. Books have two attribute `BookName(String)` & `AuthorName(CKReference)`. `Authors` have one attribute `AuthorTitle(String)`.

I save `CKReference` as follows

```
let authorReference = CKReference(record: addBookViewController.authorTitle!, action: CKReferenceAction.DeleteSelf)

bookRecord.setObject(authorReference, forKey: "AuthorName")
```

I am currently fetching `CKReference` as follows to display on table

```
let authorReference = bookRecord.objectForKey("AuthorName") as! CKReference

let authorTitle = authorReference.recordID.recordName

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = authorTitle
```

On tableview cell it shows record ID of `AuthorName`. Instead I want to see `AuthorName` in string format. How do I get it?

Comment: please show how addBookViewController.authorTitle is declared

Comment: its very complicated & requires long explanation. But I assure you that addBookViewController.authorTitle is a CKRecord of Authors. When I display authorReference.recordID.recordName on tableview I am getting correct Authors record ID as String. But I want fetch actual Authors record with this ID & show AuthorsTitle String attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AuthorName field is a reference to an other record. In order to get data from that record, you need to fetch it first.

```
database.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: authorReference.recordID), completionHandler: {record, error in
 // now you can use record.objectForKey("AuthorTitle")
}
```

Comment: I just used reference recordID in string format & it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `CKFetchRecordsOperation`

```
CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"firstRecordIDName"];
CKRecordID *recordID2 = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"secondRecordIDName"];
NSArray *arrayOfRecordIDs = @[recordID,recordID2];;
CKFetchRecordsOperation *fetchRecordsOperation = [[CKFetchRecordsOperation alloc]initWithRecordIDs:arrayOfRecordIDs];
fetchRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = ^(CKRecord *record, CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {

        // handle error

    }else {

        // Successfull fetch, create data model

    }

};
fetchRecordsOperation.database = publicDatabase;
[fetchRecordsOperation start];
```